# Hadoop - How Job executed - Need step by step explaination

Tags: hadoop

I am learning hadoop. I am trying to visualize what happen after I submit job. I mean can somebody explain step-by-step what happen when I execute command

```
hadoop jar example.jar WordCount test.txt output
```

How this Java program submitted to JobTracker. How namenode, datanode comes into picture etc.

Thanks
Aniruddha

Comment: Try this, http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/459-anatomy-of-a-mapreduce-job-run-with-hadoop/

Comment: @Praveen I dont get your question. If you mean What I did to figure-out is the explanation given in link correct or not? As I pointed out in question, I ask help to visualize how namenode, datanode & other hadoop component work together. And for that as of now I am relying on given link provide correct information.   Currently I am learning hadoop & following instructions given in book (HadoopBignnersGuide). To check what namenode,jobtracker,tasktracker doing, I am checking their UI on browser as well as checking logs when job is running. Is there any other way I can try on single machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**At the highest level, there are four independent entities:**

The **client**, which submits the MapReduce job.

The **jobtracker**, which coordinates the job run. The **jobtracker** is a Java application whose main class is **JobTracker**.

The **tasktrackers**, which run the tasks that the job has been split into. **Tasktrackers** are Java applications whose main class is **TaskTracker**.

The distributed **filesystem**, which is used for sharing job files between the other entities.

Please go through the below link

http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/459-anatomy-of-a-mapreduce-job-run-with-hadoop/

Comment: Thanks a lot for link & explaining.

Comment: Pleasure is all mine n Happy Coding:)